# How to test templates with hiera data locally?

Tags: templates, erb, puppet, hiera

I'm trying to figure out a way to take a erb template file and use hiera data (even from a single yaml file) and just use the template to generate a file with replaced values.

Have you ever tried anything like this? My first thought is to write a ruby script, but maybe there's a simpler solution.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Since it might not be clear, let me explain the use case.

I want all application configuration to be templated and committed by developers and I want to provide them an automated way of filling those templates in on their local machines (laptops) without using puppet. The extra benefit is validation of templates before actually committing them.

Comment: So *do* you need Hiera semantics, or do you want to fill variable values from a single YAML file?

Comment: I'd prefer to use Hiera semantics, but filling in variables would work I guess.

Comment: Will Puppet be involved at all? Or do you want to setup Hiera on a standalone machine that does not use Puppet, but has Hiera and Ruby/ERB?

Comment: Puppet will be involved at later stage, to configure test environments. I want to be able to fill in the configuration templates on local machines without puppet before committing them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this from hiera data directly, but it would be easy to implement with the ERB and yaml ruby libs. Something like (psudo-code):

```
class Erbwritter 
require 'erb'
require 'yaml

    attr_accessor :output_path, :yaml_path

    def initialize(template, command)
        @output = :output_path
        @data   = :yaml_path
         .....
    end

    def render()
        ERB.new(@template).result(binding)
    end

    def save(file)
        File.open(file, "w+") do |f|
            f.write(render)
        end
    end

    def parse_yaml(@data)
        File.open(@data, ...
        # parse some stuff, add them to a local {}
    end
end
```

Then, you can instance this class like:

```
newTemplate = Erbwritter.new(/path/to/output, /path/to/yaml)
newTemplate.save(File.join(Dir.pwd, your_file_name"))
```

Again, this is all basically psudo code and won't work out of the box, but it's pretty close. So have fun.

You can read more about ERB Class [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).

Comment: This looks good, basically. To marry this to Hiera proper, you should also `require 'hiera'` and add lookups like the [hiera-puppet module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/hiera-puppet/blob/bccaddc11fd7786434838b5ba26d1ecbe94b9fdd/lib/hiera_puppet.rb#L13) used to do it.